# Alarm on iPhone through Apple Watch

Tags: apple-watch

When I set an alarm on my Apple Watch, is it possible to copy this automatically to my iPhone so that both devices alert me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using the built-in apps. There might be third party applications with this functionality.